Avoiding pointless ::int cast of a number field retrieved from a JSON
Please take a look at this query:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events e WHERE (e.event_data -> 'state')::int = -1;

The query works and everything is actually ok, but...
This is how the JSON object looks like when I read it from the database:
{
  "eventUID": "3ea6baf7-8772-48a5-a32b-b00901534025",
  "data": {<some-data>},
  "state": 1
}

As you can see 'state' is an int type.
EXPLAIN ANALYZE show me this:
Aggregate  (cost=15.08..15.09 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.042..0.076 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on events e  (cost=0.00..15.07 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.018..0.027 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: (((event_data -> 'state'::text))::integer = -1)
Planning Time: 0.139 ms
Execution Time: 0.198 ms

Obviously Postgres casts an already int field to a text and then casts it again to an int.
So is it possible to avoid the cast so the select looks something like this (I know this is not valid select):
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events e WHERE e.event_data -> 'state' = -1;

Using PostgreSQL 16.

explicit cast as SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events e WHERE (e.event_data ->> 'state')::int = -1; would avoid intermediate type cast I guess..?

@SudhirBastakoti Unfortunately, I get the following from the analyzer Filter: (((event_data ->> 'state'::text))::integer = '-1'::integer)

It's the 'state' constant you used as a key that you're extracting from the JSON, that's cast to ::text. Combined with the -> operator on a JSON value, gets you a JSON on output:

json -> text → json
jsonb -> text → jsonb
Extracts JSON object field with the given key.
'{"a": {"b":"foo"}}'::json -> 'a' → {"b":"foo"}

In effect, you can read your code like this:
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM events e 
WHERE (e.event_data --no cast necessary, it's a known `json`
       -> --there are multiple operators like this
       'state'--this is an `unknown` constant, but it makes sense to interpret
              --it as `text`, because that enables a `json->text` operator
       )--the operation inside the parentheses yields a `json`
    ::int--this only works if you're sure the `json` inside is a number 
         --and if you use ->>, not a -> in there, or go through ::text
    = -1;


If you want a SQL integer rather than a JSON with a number primitive in it, that final ::int cast is necessary.

postgres casts an already int field to a text and then casts it again to an int

That is not what's happening. Only the 'state' constant is cast (actually, assigned a type) ::text by Postgres for the -> to work (it requires a text as the right operand).

If you're looking to speed up this specific query, you can add an expression index:
demo at db<>fiddle
create index on events ((event_data ->> 'state'));

For more performance and flexibility it would make sense to switch from json to jsonb and build a GIN index that would support way more types of queries on this column.

thx! so it is unpossible to avoid int cast in my case. Would it be besser for performance if I use '-1'in my query als right operand?

It wouldn't because there is no json=json operator. You could try WHERE e.event_data ->> 'state' = '-1'; because ->> extracts the value as text already but I don't think there's much performance to be gained from that, if any. If you're trying to speed things up, ask a new question and attach table and index DDL (create statements) and the output of explain(analyze,verbose,buffers,settings) added in front of your query. Or, take a look at Chapter 14. Performance Tips which explains how to use EXPLAIN, and more.

yes of cource I mean using ->>. And yes I tested it and I can't see any improvement of performance. thy very much!

Your current execution plan shows a seq scan, so you're probably missing an index entirely or the one you have isn't well adjusted to what you're doing. Without looking at anything else, if you're only/mostly querying just the 'state' key, you could try to add an expression index: create index on events ((event_data ->> 'state')) and after you vacuum analyze the table, you should see queries using WHERE e.event_data ->> 'state' = '-1' speed up and show an index scan instead of reading the whole table sequentially.

If you swapped out json for jsonb, you could get heaps more performance, save space, support more query types with a single GIN index and gain access to a ton more features that aren't available to regular json.

@devops I've added a demo showing the expression index speeding things up from 270ms to 6ms on 200k sample rows.

thats great! lol if I'm setting index as create index on events (((event_data ->> 'state')::INT)); performance boost is gone.

That shouldn't be a problem as long as you reflect that in your query: https://dbfiddle.uk/3c2PyR4p

It isn't an integer and can't be*.
Firstly, JSON doesn't have integers. It has "numbers", which could have a decimal part.
Secondly, a JSON object isn't of any fixed type anyway. The next one from the database might have a state of a string or array of objects, or perhaps not have any state at all.
So, if you want PostgreSQL to know that you promise there will always be a 32 bit signed integer value there (or an error) then you need to tell it.
* You might say "but I know all of them are ints". This is (a) only true until I come along and insert a string state and (b) no use to the database because it can't read your mind.

Yes, of course you are right. My assumption was, if I use jsonb instead of json in my table, that postgres still stores some type information and tries to do the comparison optimistically without cast for performance reasons.
